# Agreement in sentences which are related by conjunctions

Tags: sentence-construction, conjunctions

Sometimes when I relate some sentences with conjunctions I don't know if

- I should repeat the subject in the second sentence?
- I should repeat an auxiliary verb?
- I can use a verb which maybe is not in agreement with the first one?

For example :

> The user can click on the “Show the letter” button to see the correct letter **and** [then] (**continue or continues** ?) with the rest of the word.
>
> This technique helps the student to discover his common mistakes and **(improve or improves or to improve ..?)** his skill in discriminating speech sounds.

What is the general rule?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first sentence, the form of the verb in the second clause is still governed by "can" so it is plain in form: **[can click and continue]**

> The user **can click** on the “Show the letter” button to see the
>   correct letter and then **continue** with the rest of the word.

In the second, both verbs are governed by helps: **[helps him detect and improve]**

> This technique **helps** the student detect his common mistakes and
>   **improve** his ability to distinguish speech sounds.

Comment: Then if it was "to detect" then the second was "to improve" too?

Comment: if you used TO, you could use it once or repeat it: [helps him to detect x and improve y] -or- [helps him to detect x and to improve y].

Comment: I mean in general not just for the verb "help", for example can I say "*allows him to detect X and improve Y*"?

Comment: yes, i was just using your example. To answer your questions, TO can govern more than one verb: "I want, hope, have, refuse TO LIVE in this country and (TO) WORK for this company."